# JWT Authenticated API with Lumen always return 401 unauthorized on login

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, jwt

I followed [this](https://dev.to/ndiecodes/build-a-jwt-authenticated-api-with-lumen-2afm) tutorial:

```
public function login(Request $request)
        {
            //validate incoming request
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ]);

            $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
            var_dump($credentials);
            echo Auth::attempt($credentials);

            if (! $token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
            }

            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }
```

[image: I always get this error with postman the array is a vardump of my credentials]

My problem is that

> JWT Authenticated API with Lumen always return 401 unauthorized on login